# Off topic exchange with opensource.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I'm a regular contributor to the beta of opensource.stackexchange, and we semi-regularly have questions which we close as off-topic because they are about copyright in general and don't really pertain to open source.

When we close them off-topic, it would be nice to be able to offer an alternative out. Is this site a reasonable place to refer askers of those kinds of questions to? Are general copyright questions on topic here?

Conversely, if you close anything off-topic here which you feel has a (close) relation to open source/free culture, feel free to send them our way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have a healthy volume of questions tagged [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright), so this seems to potentially be a good home for such questions!

Comment: Caveat: Legal *advice* questions are off-topic here, so "about copyright" != "on-topic"

Comment: @HDE226868 ...which is why Martijn asked about pointing those questions here.

Comment: @cpast My bad, I misread it as he was talking about moving copyright questions from here to there.